# Convert ts in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, melt

I have this ts:

```
   Point       Forecast      Lo 80    Hi 80      Lo 95    Hi 95
2015.173       1.657143 0.06698996 3.247296 -0.7747861 4.089072
2015.192       1.657143 0.06698996 3.247296 -0.7747861 4.089072
2015.212       1.657143 0.06698996 3.247296 -0.7747861 4.089072
2015.231       1.657143 0.06698996 3.247296 -0.7747861 4.089072
2015.250       1.657143 0.06698996 3.247296 -0.7747861 4.089072
2015.269       1.657143 0.06698996 3.247296 -0.7747861 4.089072
2015.288       1.657143 0.06698996 3.247296 -0.7747861 4.089072
2015.308       1.657143 0.06698996 3.247296 -0.7747861 4.089072
```

How can I convert it in ts, I am using:

```
fct <- data.frame(date=as.Date(index(fca)), Y = melt(fca))
```

But I get this error:

> Error in data.frame(date = as.Date(index(fca)), Y = melt(fca)) :
>   arguments imply differing number of rows: 10, 16

Someone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The `forecast` output only looks like a data frame when you print it. But if you look at the structure with `str(fca)`, you will see the messy guts of the object.

What you see when you call `print(fca)` is a specially tailored output as a visual aid ONLY. It is not meant to hint that the underlying object is a matrix-like array.

The solution is to extract the parts you are after and create a data frame from them.

```
library(forecast)
fit <- Arima(WWWusage,c(3,1,0))
fca <- forecast(fit)
cbind.data.frame(Point=fca$mean, Lower=fca$lower, Upper=fca$upper)
#           Point Lower.80% Lower.95% Upper.80% Upper.95%
# 1   0.005151116 -1.271415 -1.947189  1.281718  1.957491
# 2  -0.170997839 -1.716453 -2.534568  1.374457  2.192572
# 3  -0.205288123 -1.782216 -2.616991  1.371640  2.206415
# 4  -0.221099340 -1.812749 -2.655317  1.370550  2.213119
# 5  -0.229741679 -1.830356 -2.677670  1.370872  2.218186
# 6  -0.234764205 -1.841557 -2.692142  1.372029  2.222614
# 7  -0.237705586 -1.849083 -2.702094  1.373671  2.226683
# 8  -0.239354235 -1.854302 -2.709204  1.375594  2.230495
# 9  -0.240158452 -1.857987 -2.714414  1.377670  2.234097
# 10 -0.240391964 -1.860607 -2.718298  1.379824  2.237514
```

**Edit**

The dates are hidden pretty well in the data. I did not find an exact date vector. I believe it is generated by the `tsp` attribute indicating the start, end, and length:

```
dates <- attr(fca$mean, "tsp")
datecol <- seq(from=dates[1], to=dates[2], by=dates[3])
```

Comment: Thanks it was what I need, only one more question can I add the date?

Comment: Thank you it helps a lot